# Как задать расположение картинки?

Tags: java, desktop

Как задать расположение картинки?
[image: описания нет]

Код который я использую для картинки:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src\\Distantion\\Bground.jpg"));
            add(background);
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src\\Distantion\\Bground.jpg")));
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("src\\Distantion\\Bground.jpg");
            ii.getImage();
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(400, 200, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT))));
```